# Automatically create linked row in a different table

Tags: mysql, database-design

What I mean is that for example if I have a table `user` with `id` `name` `prefId`, and a second table `preferences` with `id` `etc...`, is it possible that when I add a row to `user`, it would automatically create a row in `preferences` and set the row's `id` to `prefId`? Should I create the `preferences` row first and manually put its `id`? And is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triggers, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Create an insert trigger on the `user` table. In your trigger, create a record on the `preferences` table, get its id and store it in `prefId` on `user`.